# Flexbox overlaps other flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new here in Stack Overflow and I have a problem with flexbox.

I want to use a `<main>` and `<footer>` with `display: flex;` where each row of main has 2 columns with `height: 100%` of the browser and footer has 2 rows, first with 3 columns and the second only one column, both with `height: auto;`

But when I do this my footer overlaps `<main>` because its height is 100%, but I need it for the 100% of the children. Am I clear?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  src: url(../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Time Burner";
  src: url(../fonts/TimeBurner-Regular.ttf);
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex {
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}

.home {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.flex:nth-child(even) {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.flex:nth-child(odd) {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.thumb {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .flex {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .arrow {
    bottom: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- ¿Qué hacés en mi código? ¿Te gustó algo? 
  Bueno, como sea, que tengas una linda visita :) -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>OnePage</title>
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#34a853" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section class="flex home" id="inicio">
      1 - Izquierda
    </section>
    <section class="flex home">
      2 - Derecha
    </section>
    <a class="arrow" href="#3">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <section class="flex" id="3">
      3 - Izquierda
    </section>
    <section class="flex">
      4 - Derecha
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <section class="flex footer">
      5 - Footer
    </section>
  </footer>
  <a class="thumb" href="#inicio">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For .flex, change to `height: 100vh;` and then for main, remove the height property altogether.

Comment: Really thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for you layout.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  main,
  footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .main-item {
    flex:0 1 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: tomato;
  }

  .footer-item {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: lightsalmon;
  }

  .footer-item:last-child {
    flex: 0 0 100vw;
    background-color: blue;
  }

  
</style>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="main-item">m1</div>
    <div class="main-item">m2</div>
    <div class="main-item">m3</div>
    <div class="main-item">m4</div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-item">f1</div>
    <div class="footer-item">f2</div>
    <div class="footer-item">f3</div>
    <div class="footer-item">f4</div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks(Gracias), T04435.

Answer (score 0):

- Put min-height:100% on body
- Remove height:100% from body